# Resize "size of text, apps and other items" using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am currently using Selenium lib in Python to work on automation project. When the project was built up, it used specific "Scale and Layout" in windows 10 as provided in the image below

[image: Windows Settings]

However, not all laptops will have this setting preset before they run this python script. While i could change the Resolution of the screen using following code

```
driver.set_window_size(1360,768)
```

however, i could not find a method, despite lot of google search, to set the size of "text, apps and other items" option to 100%.

The reason i need this specific setting as otherwise some of the elements go non-interactable as the screen UI change.

Please note that resetting zoom to 100% did not work.

PS: I am using Chrome Webdriver

Answer (score 0):

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--window-size={desired_width},{desired_height}")
```

you can use options library for changing the width and height